# Is there a way to delete cells used in a macro without messing up the relative references?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet where I recorded macros to fill a formula into a column in excel, but it does not fill every single cell--there are certain cells I skipped over because they are either blank or a subtotal within the column. Will it be possible to delete some rows without messing up the relative references used to record the macro?

I am hoping to be able to easily edit the code somehow, or maybe there is something I can put into the code to edit itself? The purpose of this spreadsheet is to avoid a lot of manual work, so having to pick through excel code and edit out the deleted rows would defeat the purpose of macros in the first place.

piece of VBA code:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveCell.Offset(7, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]-RC[-1]"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A12"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A12").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    ActiveCell.Offset(11, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A4"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A4").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

my layout:

[image]

The subtotals and empty cells need to be skipped. Each subtotal is a sum of the cells above it, and all the other cells have a simple =A1-B1, etc.

My recorded macro is meant to fill in the =A1-B1 down the cells on a certain day, and another day a similar macro will change the formulas to =B1-C1, and so on. Is there a way to make a macro change the formula based on what formula is already in the cell?

Comment: What's your issue?

Comment: Ideally, one would use some other method of determining which cells to skip, instead of hard-coded cell addresses, for exactly the reasons you point out. If you can share a sample screenshot of your layout and the recorded code, it might be easier to suggest an alternative.

Comment: @BigBen I edited--see above. Sorry if its confusing. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain why on another day the formulas get changed to =`B1-C1`? What is the logic behind changing formulas?

Comment: This is used in an accounting setting to estimate entries needed to book, so on the first day of the month the numbers are compared to an estimate, then the next day compare to something else, and so on. The macros were written to insert a button that will automatically update what is being references based on day of the month (column A is estimate, column B is an actual).